# The "justify-items" property in Display grid only impacts a single grid item

Tags: html, css

Im new to CSS and HTML. I want to create a result form via Grid. In the provided HTML and CSS code, the `justify-items: center` style is applied to the `.result class`, which is the parent container of both `.result__score` and `.result__summary` elements. However, it seems that the justify-items: center style is not directly affecting the `.result__score` element. Would you mind reviewing my code and providing feedback on any potential omissions or areas for improvement? It would be greatly appreciated if you could explain any problems you encounter and share your thoughts on whether my code is well-structured or requires enhancements.

```css
:root {
  /* Primary Color*/
  --clr--light-red: hsl(0, 100%, 67%);
  --clr--orangey-yellow: hsl(39, 100%, 56%);
  --clr--green-teal: hsl(166, 100%, 37%);
  --clr--cobalt-blue: hsl(234, 85%, 45%);

  /* Gradients Color */
  --clr--light-slate: hsl(252, 100%, 67%);
  --clr--royal-blue: hsl(241, 81%, 54%);
  --clr--violet-blue: hsla(256, 72%, 46%, 1);
  --clr--persian-blue: hsla(241, 72%, 46%, 0);

  /* Neutral Color */
  --clr-white: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  --clr-pale-blue: hsl(221, 100%, 96%);
  --clr-light-lavender: hsl(241, 100%, 89%);
  --clr-gray-blue: Dark gray blue: hsl(224, 30%, 27%);

 /* Fonts */

  --ff--base:'Fraunces', serif;
  
/* Font Weight */  
  --fw--regular: 500;
  --fw--bold: 700;
  --fw--extra-bold: 800;
}

/*
  1. Use a more-intuitive box-sizing model.
*/
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*
    2. Remove default margin
  */
* {
  margin: 0;
}
/*
    3. Allow percentage-based heights in the application
  */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
/*
    Typographic tweaks!
    4. Add accessible line-height
    5. Improve text rendering
  */
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
/*
    6. Improve media defaults
  */
img,
picture,
video,
canvas,
svg {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
/*
    7. Remove built-in form typography styles
  */
input,
button,
textarea,
select {
  font: inherit;
}
/*
    8. Avoid text overflows
  */
p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
/*
    9. Create a root stacking context
  */
#root,
#__next {
  isolation: isolate;
}

body{
    background-color: var(--clr-white);
    font-family: var(--ff--base);
    font-weight: var(--fw--regular);
}

.result{
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="32x32"
      href="./assets/images/favicon-32x32.png"
    />
    <title>Frontend Mentor | Results summary component</title>

    <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fraunces&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" class="css" />
    <style>
      .attribution {
        font-size: 11px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .attribution a {
        color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <article class="result">
      <div class="result__score">
        <h1 class="result__header">Your Result</h1>
        <div class="flex-group">76 of 100</div>
        <p class="result__comment">Great</p>
        <p class="result__description">
          You scored higher than 65% of the people who have taken these tests.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="result__summary">
        <h1 class="result__summary_header">Summary</h1>
        <div class="result__performance">
          <p>Reaction 80 / 100</p>
          <p>Memory 92 / 100 Verbal</p>
          <p>61 / 100</p>
          <p>Visual 72 / 100</p>
        </div>
        <button class="button">Continue</button>
      </div>
    </article>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should target the `div`'s inside the `.result`, not the outer article:

So use:

```css
.result > div {
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
}
```

---

```css
:root {
  /* Primary Color*/
  --clr--light-red: hsl(0, 100%, 67%);
  --clr--orangey-yellow: hsl(39, 100%, 56%);
  --clr--green-teal: hsl(166, 100%, 37%);
  --clr--cobalt-blue: hsl(234, 85%, 45%);

  /* Gradients Color */
  --clr--light-slate: hsl(252, 100%, 67%);
  --clr--royal-blue: hsl(241, 81%, 54%);
  --clr--violet-blue: hsla(256, 72%, 46%, 1);
  --clr--persian-blue: hsla(241, 72%, 46%, 0);

  /* Neutral Color */
  --clr-white: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  --clr-pale-blue: hsl(221, 100%, 96%);
  --clr-light-lavender: hsl(241, 100%, 89%);
  --clr-gray-blue: Dark gray blue: hsl(224, 30%, 27%);

 /* Fonts */

  --ff--base:'Fraunces', serif;
  
/* Font Weight */  
  --fw--regular: 500;
  --fw--bold: 700;
  --fw--extra-bold: 800;
}

/*
  1. Use a more-intuitive box-sizing model.
*/
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*
    2. Remove default margin
  */
* {
  margin: 0;
}
/*
    3. Allow percentage-based heights in the application
  */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
/*
    Typographic tweaks!
    4. Add accessible line-height
    5. Improve text rendering
  */
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
/*
    6. Improve media defaults
  */
img,
picture,
video,
canvas,
svg {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
/*
    7. Remove built-in form typography styles
  */
input,
button,
textarea,
select {
  font: inherit;
}
/*
    8. Avoid text overflows
  */
p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
/*
    9. Create a root stacking context
  */
#root,
#__next {
  isolation: isolate;
}

body{
    background-color: var(--clr-white);
    font-family: var(--ff--base);
    font-weight: var(--fw--regular);
}

.result > div {
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="32x32"
      href="./assets/images/favicon-32x32.png"
    />
    <title>Frontend Mentor | Results summary component</title>

    <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fraunces&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" class="css" />
    <style>
      .attribution {
        font-size: 11px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .attribution a {
        color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <article class="result">
      <div class="result__score">
        <h1 class="result__header">Your Result</h1>
        <div class="flex-group">76 of 100</div>
        <p class="result__comment">Great</p>
        <p class="result__description">
          You scored higher than 65% of the people who have taken these tests.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="result__summary">
        <h1 class="result__summary_header">Summary</h1>
        <div class="result__performance">
          <p>Reaction 80 / 100</p>
          <p>Memory 92 / 100 Verbal</p>
          <p>61 / 100</p>
          <p>Visual 72 / 100</p>
        </div>
        <button class="button">Continue</button>
      </div>
    </article>

  </body>
</html>
```